# When using magic %paste in ipython, how can i get it to just paste the copied code, rather than paste and execute, so that it can be edited

Tags: ipython, paste, ipython-magic

When using magic %paste in ipython, it executes pasted code, rather than just pasting. How can i get it to just paste the copied code so that it can be edited?

Answer (score 6):

You have two options:

- To edit it by hand, run `%cpaste`. Then you can paste it in with standard terminal options (try Ctrl-Shift-V), and edit it. Enter `--` on a line to finish.
- To change it as text in your code, run `%paste foo`. It will store the clipboard contents in `foo`.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Thomas K's answer (quoted below), if you have stored statements to a string variable `foo` by using `%paste foo`, you can later run that string (or any python statements in string form) using the [`exec(foo [, globals, locals])`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-exec-statement).

> You have two options:
>
> - To edit it by hand, run `%cpaste`. Then you can paste it in with standard terminal options (try Ctrl-Shift-V), and edit it. Enter `--`
>     on a line to finish.
> - To change it as text in your code, run `%paste foo`. It will store the clipboard contents in `foo`.

Answer (score 3):

There is a solution for this issue in ipython, if you are not concerned with indentation,

Just run  `%autoindent` to Automatic indentation OFF.